# How to use the same ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC and XAMARIN

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xamarin.forms

In my ASP.NET application I have various ViewModels with annotations. 
Now I want to use these ViewModels in my XAMARIN application. 
The annotations are not intended to be used in the XAMARIN application. 
I am aware that ViewModels with and without annotations are not the same ViewModels
, but the fields are the same. But how do I reach a maximum sharing of the code?

Basically every View should have its own ViewModel.
In this case, however, it would be tempting to use ViewModels multiple times on the web, Android and iOS. (If the presented fields are equal on all plattforms.)

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace ... {
    public class Review : Atom
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Name
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 3)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Autor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Tanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [conditional compilation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_4_-_platform_divergence_abstraction_divergent_implementation/#Conditional_Compilation)

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace ... {
    public class Review : Atom
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Name
        /// </summary>
#if __MOBILE__
        // Xamarin iOS or Android-specific code
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 3)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
#endif
        public string Autor { get; set; }
    }
}
```